# How do we test whether something is a reference?

Tags: clojure

For now I'm using this:

`(instance? clojure.lang.IDeref x)`

...but I suspect there might be a better/more idiomatic way to do this.

Comment: There's a JIRA open to add a predicate for this and other built-in types: http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ-1298

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is incorrect, you are checking if the object x implements the IDeref interface, which simply means you can dereference the object with the @ symbol. What you want is this:

```
 (instance? clojure.lang.Ref x)
```

EDIT:

(Adjusting for comments).

You can do what you suggested but this has the disadvantage of classifying objects made by other users that extend IDeref to be considered a reference type. Also consider that vars also behave as reference types but do not use the IDeref interface.

There are two good options here. You can either write a function that uses an or statement:

```
 (def ref? [x] 
    (or (instance? clojure.lang.Ref x)
        (instance? clojure.lang.Agent x)
        ...))
```

Or you can use protocols to define a new predicate. This has the advantage of being extensible.

```
 (defprotocol Ireference? (reference? [this]))

 (extend-type java.lang.Object Ireference? (reference? [this] false))
 (extend-type nil Ireference (reference? [this] false))
 (extend-type clojure.lang.Ref Ireference? (reference? [this] true))
 (extend-type clojure.lang.Agent Ireference? (reference? [this] true))

 ;;user=> (reference? nil)
 ;;false
 ;;user=> (reference? (ref 0))
 ;;true
```

For another example see http://dosync.posterous.com/51626638

Comment: I would also go one step further and make it a new predicate like `(defn ref? [x] (instance? clojure.lang.Ref x))`

Comment: bmillare: I was actually asking about all "references" not just "ref", and afaik, the term "references" include refs, atoms and agents.

Comment: Also note that you can't use case with class literals like that: `(case (class "hi") String true false) -> false`

Comment: fixed the class literal problem

Comment: the (extend-type nil Ireference? (reference? [this] false)) is missing the first question mark. btw thanks.  Any idea why there is no reference? function in clojure.core?